# (Local path) Connectivity of the graph of the complex square root

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness

I am wondering if the set $S := \{(z,w): w^2 = z, w \ne 0 \} \subseteq \mathbb{C}^2$ is a connected or locally path connected space under the subspace topology? This set lives in four dimensional space so I am having a hard time visualizing the argument, which is what I usually do for proofs in topology. I have read that $S$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ (which would prove both claims), but I cannot think of an explicit homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The projection map $(z,w)\mapsto w$ is a homeomorphism from $S$ to $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, with inverse $w\mapsto (w^2,w)$.  So $S$ is connected and locally path-connected.

More generally, the graph of a continuous function $X\to Y$ is always homeomorphic to $X$.  In this case, we have the graph of a continuous function (namely, $w\mapsto w^2$ from $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ to itself), just with the order of the coordinates swapped.